# Is there a website that will tell you what class number on one campus is equivalent to what other class number but on a different campus?

Tags: coursework, transfer-student

The Problem: I'm trying to finish up my teaching credential this semester, but one of the last classes I need isn't offered by my campus.  But they say if I can find an online version of the class offered by another CSU (California State University) campus, that I can take that.

But all the CSU Campuses have their own internal course numbers, so to find out which class is equivalent to the one I need, I've been checking the catalogs, looking at the requirements, finding the course that looks close and checking the course description for a similar one to the original.

But this takes an amazing amount of time.  Maybe this is wishful thinking, but it seems like there has to be a website with a table or lookup of equivalent courses on other campuses.

Something like Physics 4A at campus A is equivalent to Physical Science 200 at Campus B.

Does this exist?  If so where might I look?

In case someone has some very specific information I'm looking for the equivalent of CI 161 from Fresno State being offered online on a different CSU Campus.

---

Additional

My advisor was able to find a teaching science middle school class, class that will be equivalent enough for the teaching high school science class.  I still think a website that gave equivalent classes would be so very useful to students.  I wonder if it's out there somewhere already.

Comment: If there is, I'd expect it is only for special situations. For example, if two unis have some special very close association and they have deliberately aligned their course work. Or if the courses are mandated by some governing body outside the university, such as certain classes in certain professional degrees, like medical doctor or lawyer.

Answer (score 3):

My department has a transfer credit evaluation committee whose job is to decide which of our requirements are satisfied by classes taken elsewhere (usually other universities, not just other campuses).  On that basis, I guess that your department has a similar committee. If you had not bothered to check  for equivalent courses but had just taken one and thought it would be equivalent (not a recommended course of action) and had then come back to your home campus and announced "I've fulfilled all the requirements; give me my diploma," then there would be some person or committee whose job is to say "Whoa; who says that this course satisfies our requirement? That's for us to decide, not you." I suggest that you ask enough questions (of your department chair, or dean, or secretaries) to find that person or committee and then ask them what courses would satisfy the requirement. In other words, get an authoritative answer from someone who has the real authority to approve (or disapprove) using a course from elsewhre to fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

https://www.collegetransfer.net/Search/Search-for-Course-Equivalencies

You can click the "Advanced" tab to search for specific course equivalencies.

Comment: I tried a simple comparison from Fresno State to CSU Northridge, and the website couldn't find Northridge.  So I'll monkey around with it, but either I'm doing something wrong or the site is too glitchy to use.

Comment: @DavidElm: I suspect the website just aggregates whatever information that it could find, which means not all universities will be included, and also that the information should probably not be deemed all that reliable.